Intenté respaldar mi un programa y me aparece este error "General SQL error.]
Intenté respaldar una aplicación de nóminas y me apareció este error
"General SQL error. [Microsoft] [ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server] [SQL Server] Changed database context to 'master'.
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server] [SQL Server] Database 'mi empresa s.a' cannot be opened. It is in the middle of a

Cómo estas generando el backup??

"It's in the middle of a" Nos has dejado con el suspense. ¿Qué estará haciendo esa base de datos que la has pillado justamente enmedio del meollo?
